# Getting the following error while attaching a process on Visual Studio to debug a C++ code

Tags: java, c++, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I have a project that works on both Java and C++ code

To debug the same, I have followed tutorials online to attach a `javaw.exe` process (from the Eclipse IDE) to the C++ code on Visual Studio 2012 IDE.

I have waited until the `dll` file has been loaded and just before the C++ code is invoked from the Java code, went to the Visual Studio 2012 IDE to attach the process `javaw.exe` to hit the breakpoint on the C++ code. The moment I add the process to Visual Studio 2012 IDE, getting this error and the breakpoint is never reachable.

Can anybody look into this and help me? I should be missing a trivial detail here in the debug process!

I'm unable to get any solutions from the other posts on similar topics get to work in my case!

Followed [this](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/DebuggingJNICAndJavaCodeInEclipse?_sscc=t) complete post to set-up the actual debugging process.

```
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\javaw.exe'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\lpk.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\usp10.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.18837_none_fa3b1e3d17594757\comctl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wsock32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ws2_32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nsi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\version.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\psapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\bin\verify.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\bin\java.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\bin\zip.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptsp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rsaenh.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\userenv.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\bin\net.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mswsock.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\IPHLPAPI.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winnsi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dhcpcsvc6.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dhcpcsvc.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\bin\nio.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Softwares\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316\eclipse_1608.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nlaapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\NapiNSP.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\pnrpnsp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dnsapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\WSHTCPIP.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rasadhlp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\FWPUCLNT.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Softwares\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\136\0\.cp\jWinHttp-1.0.0.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winhttp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\webio.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sspicli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\credssp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Softwares\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\741\0\.cp\swt-win32-4430.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\comdlg32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winspool.drv'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wininet.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\api-ms-win-downlevel-user32-l1-1-0.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\api-ms-win-downlevel-shlwapi-l1-1-0.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\api-ms-win-downlevel-version-l1-1-0.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\api-ms-win-downlevel-normaliz-l1-1-0.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\normaliz.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\iertutil.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\api-ms-win-downlevel-advapi32-l1-1-0.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\crypt32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msasn1.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\propsys.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\clbcatq.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Softwares\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\741\0\.cp\swt-gdip-win32-4430.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.7601.23545_none_14599ab28b920323\GdiPlus.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsCodecs.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleacc.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Softwares\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\133\0\.cp\os\win32\x86_64\localfile_1_0_0.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msimg32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mlang.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\bin\sunec.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\RpcRtRemote.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ExplorerFrame.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\duser.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dui70.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntmarta.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Wldap32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\apphelp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntshrui.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\srvcli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\setupapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\devobj.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cscapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\slc.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\atl100.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseStub.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseSVN.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\libsvn_tsvn.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\libapr_tsvn.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\libaprutil_tsvn.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\intl3_tsvn.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\libsasl.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\secur32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp100.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\netutils.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\linkinfo.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mssprxy.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'javaw.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\kravki\AppData\Local\Temp\jna--994581618\jna11439137237234443.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
The thread 0x25d4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3f38 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

When I point to a breakpoint that I was intending to see hit from the Java code, I see the following message:

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document

Is there something that I have to do, to enable debugging Java / C++ code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: PDB is an acronym for Program DataBase. A PDB file is a file that contains the debug information used by Visual Studio. Unless you want to debug any of the libraries listed you don't need those libraries PDB files, only the ones for the libraries/programs you want to debug. Also, if you want to debug your library/program, you should build it in debug mode, so it actually *have* a PDB file generated for it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I did do that - I built my application in the debug mode! I can see that the `.pdb` file is generated too, but still the error!

Comment: "getting this error" - which error?

Comment: @ThomasWeller, added the complete set. Not completely a stacktrace but that's what I'm facing. Unable to get the debugger on to the C++ code from Java